# Why doesn't Emacs accept keyboard input in timers?

Tags: debugging

I've managed to write a timer that reliably causes keyboard input not to be accepted until I press `Ctrl-G`.

The issue is, I don't know what causes the timer to lock up, what the stack frame is when it's locked up, or how to unlock it.

- `(signal 'quit)` resolves the issue but this isn't a reasonable fix.
- Using gdb doesn't point to a function which is blocking input.
- `toggle-debug-on-quit` doesn't give a useful stack trace.

---

In Python I can press Ctrl-C to get a stack trace of the code being executed. Why doesn't Emacs let me interrupt my timer's code with `C-g`?

Comment: What do you mean by "(signal 'quit) resolves the issue"?  How/when can your code decide to call `(signal 'quit)`?

Comment: timer code always runs with `inhibit-quit` bound to a non-nil value (so that it doesn't get accidentally aborted just because the user hit `C-g` at that moment for some completely unrelated reason (e.g. to get out of a minibuffer)).

Comment: Have you tried sending SIGUSR2 to Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `toggle-debug-on-quit` will help.

> Toggle whether to enter Lisp debugger when C-g is pressed.